# Set authentication XMLHTTP export HTML

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying the following code so as to be able to export specific HTML page but the website requires credentials. Here's my try

```
Sub NewTest()
Const sURL As String = "https://courses.myexcelonline.com/courses/take/microsoft-teams/lessons/11482643-microsoft-teams-course-overview"
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim sUser As String, sPass As String
sUser = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("myemail")
sPass = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("mypass")

Dim postData As String
postData = "user%5Bemail%5D=" & sUser & "&user%5Bpassword%5D=" & sPass

With http
    .Open "POST", sURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send postData
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    ExportHTML .responseText
End With

Stop
End Sub

Sub ExportHTML(sInput As String)
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .Open
    .WriteText sInput
    .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\OutputHTML.html", 2
    .Close
End With
End Sub
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code .. I expect to have specific HTML page stored on my desktop but when I open the HTML page I didn't find the page but find the credentials request for email and password.

I have changed the url and this fixed the problem I think `Const sURL As String = "https://courses.myexcelonline.com/users/sign_in"`. But I need to know how to get specific HTML page from the site?

Comment: What is your Excel version? In my version I am asking because there is no WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using Office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're sending a "GET" instead of "POST".

Since you are sending POST data with your request, you need to change the "GET" to "POST'

```
.Open "Get", sURL, False
```

To

```
.Open "POST", sURL, False
```

EDIT :
The URL you provided does not correlate to a POST, but rather a GET.

You need to send a GET request to the login page first, followed by a POST to the same login URL page it is - https://courses.myexcelonline.com/users/sign_in, followed by a GET to your original URL provided since by that moment you're already logged in and can navigate to your URL correctly.

Here is an example POST data - The authenticity token can be found when you send you send the first GET to the login page in the HTML. To do this, get the .responseText after the GET request. You can then use the Split function to get the auth token like this.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="ReGa49vTQ0KqSZtje3VerA8q3O9J1RLO7lEU/+q1hccys6S1uXn6UigKiKTjDp2yEFQRpYpziRQLnXifJLxb+Q==" />

Dim authToken As String
authToken = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(Split(Split(http.responseText, "csrf-token"" content=""")(1), """")(0))

Dim postData As String
postdata = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=" & authToken & "&user%5Bemail%5D=" & sUser & "&user%5Bpassword%5D=" & sPass & "&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0"
```

Here is the final code

```
Sub NewTest()
Const sURL As String = "https://courses.myexcelonline.com/courses/take/microsoft-teams/lessons/11482643-microsoft-teams-course-overview"
Const sLoginURL As String = "https://courses.myexcelonline.com/users/sign_in"
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim sUser As String, sPass As String, sAuthToken As String, postData As String
sUser = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("myemail")
sPass = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("mypass")

'Load Login Page
With http
    .Open "GET", sLoginURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
    .WaitForResponse
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

'Get Auth Token from HTML
sAuthToken = Application.WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL((Split( (Split(http.body.innerHTML, "csrf-token"" content=""")(1)), """")(0)))

'Construct the POST data that will be sent
postData = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=" & sAuthToken & "&user%5Bemail%5D=" & sUser & "&user%5Bpassword%5D=" & sPass & "&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0"

'Attempt to login 
With http
    .Open "POST", sLoginURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send (postData)
    .WaitForResponse
End With

'Add code here to verify if login was successful...

'If successful... navigate to sURL 
With http
    .Open "GET", sURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send 
    .WaitForResponse
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    ExportHTML .responseText
End With

Stop
End Sub

Sub ExportHTML(sInput As String)
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .Open
    .WriteText sInput
    .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\OutputHTML.html", 2
    .Close
End With
End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this doesn't solve the problem. But you are right as I had to use POST not GET.

Comment: I have changed the url and this fixed the problem I think `Const sURL As String = "https://courses.myexcelonline.com/users/sign_in"`. But I need to know how to get specific HTML page from the site?

Comment: I edited my comment, this should allow you to load the login page, login, then navigate to your original URL.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. What shall I do now using POST or GET? and What URL should I use? ..Can you post the whole code after modification so as to have an overview look?

Comment: Added final code after modification, let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel this is a long path in this way. I thought it is simpler than all of that. :(

Comment: Yeah, authentication can be tricky. I use the developer options in Chrome, specifically the Network tab, to see the requests. You can check each request and see if it was a GET or a POST and what post data was sent, as well as retrieving any headers required for the request. So, did it work?

Comment: I am not sure. All what I got when I inspected the local exported HTML is a head section with a lot of Script tags.

Comment: If the HTML is updated on the fly via AJAX/JavaScript, the .responseText will not have the updated HTML. You can view page source to see if there are things on the page that are also in the source (using a web browser). If you can't find them, that means the HTML was updated via AJAX/JavaScript which can't be retrieved via XMLHTTP object or any HTTP object for that matter. You'll have to use another web scraping method generally InternetExplorer or Selenium.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems that is updated using AJAX/JS. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd recommend looking at this if you are willing to use Selenium instead of InternetExplorer which I find to be much easier - https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/